# Does the pin in Steins;Gate pose any information paradox?

Tags: steins-gate

In *Steins;Gate*, Suzuha brings the lab member a pin to the past.

[image: the pin]

Okabe remembers the pin and makes one in future, does this pose information paradox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Steins;Gate was set on a single timeline then you could describe this exchange as an information paradox. However, the series is known to use a multiple timelines model, which can allow for this case:

- Timeline A: Someone (Okabe?) designs the pin.
- Timeline B,C,D,...: The story unfolds, the pin may or may not have already been created in the different timelines, and may or may not have been shown by Suzuha at all.
- Timeline Z (that is not A): The timeline in which Suzuha brings the pin To Okabe AND Okabe ends up recreating it.

Of course, the information paradox could still apply in the multiple timelines model (if timelines Z and A were one and the same), even though it is more likely to have taken place over multiple timelines without looping back, with a clear start and end.

Comment: This is correct. Though it's pretty much confirmed that no matter how small, any and all changes in the past always shifts the world line so whatever information coming from the future always leads to a new world line (including the future where the information originated) and so the information paradox is impossible in the time travel used in *Steins;Gate*.